# how to capture a vim macro within register reuse

Tags: command-line, vim

I need to record *or code* a vim macro that captures the current line into a register and then calls an external command like figlet to make it a title form.

Something like:

```
qp
"add
```

So here I have the text in named "a" register. Then I need to call it in:

```
:r! figlet ^Ra
```

then make it a macro in .vimrc:

```
let @q='"add:r! figlet <c-r>a'
```

but then it fails with inserting the `add:r! figlet` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you want to do. It seems like you want to select text in a buffer, enter a command, and have figlet replace the selected text with its version.

If that's the case, you don't have to put the selected text in a register. Just `:!figlet` will do the job. (I just tried it. Kinda cool.)